# Could not open address book due to Desktopcouch error

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one, thunderbird

I am using Thunderbird with ubuntu since 2007. after the upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10 Ubuntu one show me this alert: <

> "could not open address book" There was a problem opening the address book "Ubuntu One" - the message returned was: Cannot open book: Could not create DesktopcouchSession object>.

Please what is the meaning of the message and, overall, what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu One can be used to sync files, but also CouchDB databases. Thunderbird has a method to store an addressbook in your DesktopCouch (personal CouchDB) so that it can be synced between your computers. However, for some reason, it is not working. It's likely a bug in Thunderbird.

If you want to follow the progress of this bug, or add yourself as affected, you can find the bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/desktopcouch/+bug/872639

Comment: Thank you, I have read your link and now it is all clear, I have only to wait

Answer (score 0):

http://ubuntuforums.org/newreply.php?do=newreply&noquote=1&p=11423806

The above link helped me to solve the issue. Something to do with disabling an extension.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference, especially since that cannot be accessed without an Ubuntu Forums account.